# Iterate through a list and remove markers from google map in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm building a map based app, and I have a realtime database of users in firebase.
I want to draw markers of all online users on the map, and remove the marker if the user matching it went offline.

I'm storing the markers that are currently on the map in a pair, which it's value is the UID of the user matching the marker. (markers are stored in a list)

I succeeded in drawing the markers on the map, but failed removing them.
**This is the relevant code (inside onMapReady, in the map activity):**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        // --- Anonymous class ---

        // list to hold online users
        List<User> onlineUsers;

        // list to hold offline users
        List<User> offlineUsers;

        // list to hold active markers
        List<Pair<String, Marker>> activeMarkers;

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            onlineUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
            offlineUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
            activeMarkers = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Marker>>();


            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (ds.child("_online").getValue(Boolean.class)) {
                    onlineUsers.add(ds.getValue(User.class));
                } else {
                    offlineUsers.add(ds.getValue(User.class));
                }
            }
            // draw marker on the map, of all online users
            for (User user : onlineUsers) {
                if (!user.get_uid().equals(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()) && user.get_currentLocation() != null) {
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(new LatLng(user.get_currentLocation().getLatitude(), user.get_currentLocation().getLongitude()));
                    markerOptions.title(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                    // add a "marker pair" to the active markers list that indicates
                    // active markers on the map.
                    activeMarkers.add(new Pair<String, Marker>(user.get_uid(), mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)));
                }
            }

            // remove marker of offline user if exists
            for(User user : offlineUsers) {
                for(int i=0 ; i<activeMarkers.size() ; i++) {
                    if(activeMarkers.get(i).first.equals(user.get_uid())) {
                        // removes the marker from the list and from the map
                        activeMarkers.remove(i).second.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

nothing is happening when user is going offline (when "_online" field is changing to false in the database). I logged the lists and values are being added to them correctly.
**What am I missing? Thank you for the help.** (If any additional code or information is needed, let me know)

Comment: So what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo The markers aren't being removed.
This section of the code:
`// remove marker of offline user if exists
            for(User user : offlineUsers) {
                for(int i=0 ; i<activeMarkers.size() ; i++) {
                    if(activeMarkers.get(i).first.equals(user.get_uid())) {
                        // removes the marker from the list and from the map
                        activeMarkers.remove(i).second.remove();
                    }
                }
            }`

Comment: You likely have multiple markers added for each user - from what I see on every data change (any user state change) you add all users to map and remove any not online - but you don't clear the map at any point so you'll keep adding markers for online users.  So your remove code may work but if there are multiple markers at that location for that user you would never see the result.

Comment: If the above is true then consider using **Maps** instead of **lists** to make it simpler to remove and replace duplicate markers. I suggest a `HashMap` so you can use the uids as keys and the markers as values.